# How to apply the same naming strategy to @Index columnList as for column?

Tags: hibernate-mapping, jbpm

Since one of the newer releases of the JBPM was added an indexes internal classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Attachment",
   indexes = {@Index(name = "IDX_Attachment_Id",  
   columnList="attachedBy_id"),
              @Index(name = "IDX_Attachment_DataId", 
   columnList="TaskData_Attachments_Id")})

@SequenceGenerator(name="attachmentIdSeq", 
   sequenceName="ATTACHMENT_ID_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
public class AttachmentImpl implements InternalAttachment {
   ...

   @ManyToOne()
   private UserImpl   attachedBy;

   ...
}
```

**attachedBy_id** column from the index columnList named **attached_by_id** in the database.
Hibernate cannot recognize correct physical column name and throws an exception:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (attachedBy_id) on table attachment: database column 'attachedBy_id' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)

I can't change the code of the JBPM. I don't want to change the column name in the database as well (it doesn't help anyway), but I need to map **attachedBy_id** from @Index columnList to **attached_by_id** in some way. Is it possible to apply the same naming strategy to the index columnList?

Comment: what version of jbpm are you using? What is your database?

Comment: this problem occurred since jbpm 7.9.0, db is postgres

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `@JoinColumn`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "attached_by_id")
private UserImpl attachedBy;
```

And you need to update the `@Index` as well:

```
@Index(name = "IDX_Attachment_Id", columnList="attached_by_id"
```

Comment: But you can supply the mappings via orm.xml and override the annotation-based ones.

Comment: if I provide orm.xml and define mappings there, annotations will not be used?

Comment: By default, they can be used together, and XML takes precedence